# bind9 problem - named: user 'bindi' unknown

Tags: networking, server, dns

I've installed bind9 on ubuntu 18.04 desktop version some days ago and worked fine...

There are many tutorial for this DNS, but this was easy and maybe ubuntu specific: [Configuration](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/dns-configuration.html.en#dns-primarymaster-configuration) I've used the primary master section, so my config files are the same as those excepted the ip addresses and the dns name. I've checked them of course, everything looks correct.

After that I didn't change anything in bind9 configuration files, just installed virtualbox and 1 guest and not anything else, but noticed that

```
ping -c2 myservername.com
ping: myservername.com: Name or service is unknown
```

Checking again... No changes in config files, reading syslog:

```
cat /var/log/syslog

...

Nov  6 19:15:25 zwh0 named[17636]: named: user 'bindi' unknown
Nov  6 19:15:25 zwh0 systemd[1]: bind9.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov  6 19:15:25 zwh0 systemd[1]: bind9.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I didn't add 'bindi' user of course,  nowhere...

What could I do wrong? Where can be the problem?
Has anybody got idea?
If You need any output, just ask, please.

[/etc/bind/named.conf.local](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/z5MwBRSGV8/)

[/etc/bind/db.myservername.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/z5MwBRSGV8/)

[/etc/bind/db.192](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/z5MwBRSGV8/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the username should be `bind`, not `bindi`. I believe this is configured in `/etc/default/bind9`:

```
cat /etc/default/bind9 
# run resolvconf?
RESOLVCONF=no

# startup options for the server
OPTIONS="-u bind"
```

Check that it doesn't say `-u bindi` under options.